# Create Vars from Facts Ansible and Jinja2

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Crating Vars from Ansible Facts

Updated: I have four systems, in those I need to extract facts then use them as variables on a jinja 2 template. The real host names have a prefix with a dash in it which makes it difficult to use the whole host name as variable. Systems are setup as:

```
office1
    debn-web01
    ubun-web02

office2
    linx-web01
    linx-web02
```

In the Ansible play I have:

```
vars:
    office1:
       web01:
          myip: 10.10.10.10
          peer: 10.10.10.20
       web02:
          myip: 10.10.10.20
          peer: 10.10.10.10

    office2:
       web01:
          myip: 10.20.20.30
          peer: 10.20.20.40
       web02:
          myip: 10.20.20.40
          peer: 10.20.20.30
```

I would like to extract the hostname part after the dash on the host name, ie "debn-web01" -> "web01" to use it as a the previously created ansible variable.

So on the Jinja2 template I have:

```
# This should create the var: web01
{% set trimd_hostname = ansible_hostname.split("-")[1] %}

# Start of Ansible Config File:
host_name: {{ ansible_hostname }}
web01 host_ip: {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
host_peer: {{ office1[ trimd_hostname ]peer }}
```

The trim option is working as I can print the output by itself on a template. I however get error that peer is not a variable object of office1.trimd_hostname.

Comment: You're missing a `.` in `office1[trimd_hostname]peer`.  You want `office1[trimd_hostname].peer`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question is a little tricky because you haven't posted a complete reproducer. That means this question may be a little off, because I've had to make some assumptions about what you're doing.

If I try to reproduce your problem with the following example playbook, it works without errors:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    office1:
      web01:
        myip: 10.10.10.10
        peer: 10.10.10.20
      web02:
        myip: 10.10.10.20
        peer: 10.10.10.10

    office2:
      web01:
        myip: 10.20.20.30
        peer: 10.20.20.40
      web02:
        myip: 10.20.20.40
        peer: 10.20.20.30
    trimd_hostname: web01
    ansible_hostname: debn-web01
    ansible_eth0:
      ipv4:
        address: 1.2.3.4
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: ./output.txt
        content: |
          {% set trimd_hostname = ansible_hostname.split("-")[1] %}
          host_name: {{ ansible_hostname }}
          web01 host_ip: {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
          host_peer: {{ office1[trimd_hostname].peer }}
```

That produces the following in `output.txt`:

```
host_name: debn-web01
web01 host_ip: 1.2.3.4
host_peer: 10.10.10.20
```

I've already pointed out a typo in your question, but it's hard to tell if that's an actual error or if that was just a copy/paste error when you were writing the question.

I'd like to suggest a different way of organization your data.  Get rid of the `office1` and `office2` variables, and instead use ansible [host_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data) to store the information.

That is, create `host_vars/dbn-web01.yml` with the following content:

```
myip: 10.10.10.10
peer: 10.10.10.20
```

And similarly for the other hosts.  Then your template becomes simply:

```
host_name: {{ ansible_hostname }}
web01 host_ip: {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
host_peer: {{ peer }}
```

The value of the `peer` variable will be whatever is appropriate for the particular host on which the task is running.

Comment: thanks larsk, to clarify, office1 and office2 must be included as these defined other variable as gateway, ip ranges etc. However, If I use this proposed method, does it means that on the template I have to define every possible host as `web01 host_ip: {{ ipv4.address }} and if web02 host_ip:{{ ipv4.address }}` etc? The possible method I am thinking of is that of a single entry on template no matter the host-name, similar to `office1.{{ whatever_hostname }}.peer or office1.{{ whatever_hostname }}.ipv4.address `